# Round Corners Box Geometry - threejs

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, geometry

This question is more about Math, than about threejs but maybe there are usable Alternatives for my issue.

[image: Example Image for issue]

So what I want to do, is to go through every vertice in a Box Geometry and check weither it has to be moved down/up and move it then by a specific value. (it is only about the y-values of each vertice)

```
var width = 200,
    height = 100,
    depth = 50;
var roundCornerWidth = var roundCornerHeight = 10;
var helpWidth = width - 2*roundCornerWidth,
    helpHeight = height - 2*roundCornerHeight;

var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth, 100, 50, 10);
boxGeometry.vertices.forEach(v => {
  if(Math.abs(v.x)>helpWidth/2){
    if(Math.abs(v.y)>helpHeight/2){
      let helper = Math.abs(v.x)-helperWidth/2;
      v.y = Math.sign(v.y)*(helperHeight + Math.cos(helper/roundWidth * Math.PI/2)*roundHeight);
    }
  }
});
```

The code above creates corners like you can see on the example image. Those aren't kind of beautiful! :( 
Another "function" than `cos()` is needed.

Comment: What is it that you *actually* want to do here? Is this section of geometry at the corner of a larger "box", and you want to make it round? If so you could use the equation for a sphere: `v.y = Math.sqrt(width * width - v.x * v.x);`

Comment: the example image is related to each corner of the box. I want to round all  the corners of a box. the Problem has to solved inside the geometry (I do not want to use other geometries for faking the corners), because an image is mapped on the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a method without trigonometrical functions, as we can manipulate with vectors:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(50, 50, 150);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var radius = 10;
var width = 200,
  height = 100;
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, 50, 100, 50, 10);

var v1 = new THREE.Vector3();
var w1 = (width - (radius * 2)) * 0.5,
  h1 = (height - (radius * 2)) * 0.5;
var vTemp = new THREE.Vector3(),
  vSign = new THREE.Vector3(),
  vRad = new THREE.Vector3();
geometry.vertices.forEach(v => {
  v1.set(w1, h1, v.z);
  vTemp.multiplyVectors(v1, vSign.set(Math.sign(v.x), Math.sign(v.y), 1));
  vRad.subVectors(v, vTemp);
  if (Math.abs(v.x) > v1.x && Math.abs(v.y) > v1.y && vRad.length() > radius) {
    vRad.setLength(radius).add(vTemp);
    v.copy(vRad);
  }
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua",
  wireframe: true
}));
scene.add(mesh);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/90/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Disadvantage: you can't control the smoothness of the roundness without increasing the amount of width or height or depth segments.

Comment: this is clever mate! I think your solution seems to be kind of smoother than mine.

Comment: @questionAccount You're welcome :) If you're interested, check those threads: [Round-edged box](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/round-edged-box/1402), [Round-edged box 2](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/round-edged-box-2/1448), [Round-edged box 3](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/round-edged-box-3/1481).

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: copied surrounding Code Blocks from [prisoner849](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4045502/prisoner849) to make result visbile for everyone.

I wanted to stay with the box Geometry, because I also deform the Geometry on the z-axis, so this is my solution:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(50, 50, 150);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
var width = 200,
    height = 100,
    depth = 50;
var roundCornerWidth = roundCornerHeight = 10;
var helpWidth = width - 2*roundCornerWidth,
    helpHeight = height - 2*roundCornerHeight;

var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth, 100, 50, 10);
boxGeometry.vertices.forEach(v => {
  if(Math.abs(v.x)>helpWidth/2){
    if(Math.abs(v.y)>helpHeight/2){
      let helperX = Math.abs(v.x)-helpWidth/2;
      let helperY2 = (Math.abs(v.y)-helpHeight/2)/roundCornerHeight;
      let helperY = (1-helperX/roundCornerWidth) * roundCornerHeight * helperY2;
      v.y = Math.sign(v.y)*((helpHeight/2 + helperY)+(Math.sin(helperX/roundCornerWidth * Math.PI)*(roundCornerHeight/4))*helperY2);
      v.x = Math.sign(v.x)*(Math.abs(v.x)+(Math.sin(helperX/roundCornerWidth * Math.PI)*(roundCornerWidth/4))*helperY2);
    }
  }
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffce00,
  wireframe: true
}));
scene.add(mesh);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/90/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

This worked for me perfectly and seems to be the simplest solution for my issue.

Comment: It's interesting to see the wireframe result.

Comment: super curious to see what this does as well

Comment: you are right, the wireframe result was bad but I fixed that.